# Not able to start app in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Just to let you know, I'm not a programmer at all so I'm kind of lost in my problem. I'm trying to migrate an app from a Windows Server 2003 server on Apache Tomcat 4.1 and Java 1.4.2 (App is working fine on that server). I'm tried migrating it on a Windows Server 2008 R2 with any version of Apache Tomcat and Java compatible with W2KR2 but I'm always getting the same error when I try to start the app from the web interface:

```
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/GestClientsAS2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3780)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload(HostConfig.java:1307)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1290)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1474)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1369)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5083)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

I believe there is a class missing? How would I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Add the jar to tomcat/lib or define path-to-jar-file in the class path so that tomcat can refer to.

Comment: And now for a human readable comment: Possibly a library was (wrongfully) added to the old server that you did not copy to the new server. Do a search for *.jar on the old server and on the new server and compare the results. You are looking for a library related to 'javamail'.

Comment: You are missing the `MimeBodyPart` class. You can find the JAR here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavamailmailapi14jar.htm

Comment: I'm guessing I have to put that jar file in the lib folder? Should I restart the server or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you told me you application was running in a java 1.4 version, and this class is only default in Java 5+ version (See documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html), you will have to import it to your project.

Download it: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavamailmailapi14jar.htm
Since it is a web application, put this jar file inside, WEB-INF/libs, so, the classloader will load it, restart the server.

if its not a web project you can right click on the library and go to "Build Path" -> "Add to Build Path".

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I'm getting a different error now but its security related so I should be able to fix that one

Comment: Ok, so, if you can, mark it as the correct answer, and if you need anything else, just create another topic and i can help you out :)